# Trivial Swift Package builds through XCode but not via 'swift build' - the later complains about missing .h header files

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, macos

Essentially what the subject says (I'm new to the Swift ecosystem). You can download the full package here:

```
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dqjJACKX1cIVUk-cwxZxOEd8taKAU1i3/view?usp=share_link
```

My package is fairly simple:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v9), .macOS(.v10_13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
            targets: ["McuMgr.Bindings.iOS"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            name: "McuMgr",
            url: "https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git",
            .exact("0.13.0")
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
            path: "Source",
            exclude:["Info.plist"]
        )
    ]
)
```

But 'swift build' complains that dependency 'ios-nrf-connect-device-manager' is not used by any target and then it fails to compile

```
% swift build 
Fetching https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git from cache
Fetching https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git from cache
Fetched https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git (0.48s)
Fetched https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git (0.48s)
Computing version for https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git
Computed https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git at 0.13.0 (0.49s)
Computing version for https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git
Computed https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git at 0.4.4 (0.46s)
Creating working copy for https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git
Working copy of https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git resolved at 0.13.0
Creating working copy for https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git
Working copy of https://github.com/unrelentingtech/SwiftCBOR.git resolved at 0.4.4
warning: dependency 'ios-nrf-connect-device-manager' is not used by any target
Building for debugging...
/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/McuManager-Swift.h' not found
    header "/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/McuManager-Swift.h"
           ^
/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/Source/iOSFirmwareUpgrader.swift:1:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'McuManager'
import McuManager
       ^
/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/McuManager-Swift.h' not found
    header "/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/McuManager.build/McuManager-Swift.h"
           ^
/Users/acme/Repos/cmps/mcumgr.dev/bindings/Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS/Source/iOSFirmwareUpgrader.swift:1:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'McuManager'
import McuManager
       ^
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `import McuManager` but your Package.swift doesn't define a package or dependency named `McuManager`.

You need to ensure the package names match, and explicitly add `McuManager` as a dependency of your target.

Update your `Package.swift` to

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v9), .macOS(.v10_13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
            targets: ["Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            name: "McuManager", // << updated package name
            url: "https://github.com/Laerdal/IOS-nRF-Connect-Device-Manager.git",
            .exact("0.13.0")
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Laerdal.McuMgr.Bindings.iOS",
            dependencies: ["McuManager"], // << added depedency
            path: "Source",
            exclude:["Info.plist"]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Cool. But how come the build works in XCode but not on the command line? Isn't it weird?

Comment: @XDS Xcode generates the module headers and uses the xcodebuild build system. I don't know the specific differences, but it seems the problem you ran into is one of the symptoms.